# How can I install IDLE and Anaconda(python 3.6) simulteneously?

Tags: python, anaconda, python-idle

I'm a python noobie. I have downloaded Anaconda and using jupyter notebook environment for python coding. But sometimes its getting difficult for me understand things. So I was thinking to go back to the basic IDLE environment. Is it possible to install IDLE while having Anaconda(python 3.6) installed?

P.S: I want to have both environments with same Python 3.6 version. Is it possible?

Comment: Anaconda already includes IDLE alongside Jupyter and Spyder. It may not be obvious how to run it, but you have to tell us which platform you're on before we can tell you how to do it. IIRC, on Windows you have to manually run `\path\to\Anaconda\Lib\idle\idle.bat` (you can make a shortcut to that, or put it on your PATH, etc.); on Linux it should just be `idle` or `idle3` (I forget which); on Mac… I forget (it might just be `idle3`, but it might be some horrible `open` invocation, and it might be buried inside a Framework…), but could track it down.

Comment: Meanwhile, you probably don't want to set up a whole separate Python environment just to use two different IDEs. It's much simpler and cleaned to just run IDLE and Jupyter from the same Anaconda Python environment.